# Datadog AWS EBS Monitoring - Drive Space - Exclude /dev/loop* devices

Tags: amazon-web-services, ubuntu, ubuntu-18.04, datadog, aws-ebs

Okay, here is my setup:

- Platform: AWS
- Monitoring: DataDog
- Metric: system.disk.in_use

Question: So I am running Ubuntu 18.04LTS instances and as time goes on, it seems to spawn additional devices periodically:

device:/dev/loop1, /dev/loop2 and so on.

When I first spun up these instances, there were only 3 /dev/loop(1-3) devices, however, over time, a /dev/loop4 showed up and our drive space alert paged me since these are 100% utilized when created.

So, I have to go into each of the monitors (one per environment) and add an exclusion for the new /dev/loop4, but I cannot set the exclusion until it has been created by at least one of the monitored instances.

Is there a way in DataDog that you can just add a blanket exclusion like:

device:/dev/loop*?

I have been combing through documentation and have not been able to find anything, so I thought I would ask here.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `!` and `*`, like in:

```
avg:system.disk.in_use{!device:/dev/loop*} by {host,device}
```

[source](https://www.datadoghq.com/blog/wildcard-filter-queries/)

Comment: I tried to follow the source: `max:system.disk.in_use{env:digitalocean AND !device:/dev/loop*} by {device} * 100`, but DD says: `Error parsing query: 'AND' and 'OR' cannot be mixed with ','`. It looks like I should use different syntax: https://docs.datadoghq.com/tracing/trace_explorer/query_syntax/

Comment: Another link: https://docs.datadoghq.com/metrics/advanced-filtering/

Answer (score 3):

I solved this by adding 'squashfs' to the list of filesystem types to be ignored by the datadog agent.

Create a file `/etc/datadog-agent/conf.d/disk.d/conf.yaml`:

```
init_config:
    file_system_global_blacklist:
      - iso9660$
      - squashfs

instances:
  - use_mount: false
```

Restart datadog agent (`systemctl restart datadog-agent`).

Comment: This has been renamed to `file_system_global_exclude` in newer versions of the datadog agent.